# Updateable subform adds "#http://#" to end of hyperlink field when edited

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, subform

I have a form with a subform that lists current material information being entered on the main form, like a log/history view.

On the subform there is a field that specifies which skid the product was assigned. I made this field a hyperlink so that I could use the OnClick event to launch a report and be able to extract row information needed to generate the proper summary.

That works great, and I thought it was finished until I attempted to edit the skid number from within the subform.

Allowing edits in the subform is a project requirement. Editing the skid number in the hyperlinked field breaks my code. Access automatically appends `#http://#` to the end of whatever value I enter into the cell and updates the table with this string. That row then gets omitted from the report because I'm keying off of the skid numbers. By design, this hyperlink has no path or address, I just use it to determine which row is being clicked.

How can I prevent Access from appending the `#http://#` while keeping the "Is Hyperlink" property to Yes? Is there another property to set this behavior or should I use the AfterUpdate event to undo the addition, which just seems like a waste of resources?

I am running Access 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a long and very thorough article [here](http://www.codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=access-hyperlink-data-type) that I will not copy ;) It elaborately states why its a bad idea to even use the hyperlink-field and what to do to get the same result you need without a hyperlink-field.
Basically, the main point of the hyperlink-field is all that behind the scenes shenanigans you cannot do anything about - and thats not what you want as a programmer.
The Hyperlink-field internally consists of three parts: A Text-part, a Link-Part and a Tooltip-Part. And although you can access them separately, access always tries to create a link.

You can try to format the data you have in the internally used format `(DisplayText#Address#SubAddress)` but I think that is not what you need...

So I think you best take Philipps advice and change your field-type.

Comment: My data type was text, the subform "Is Hyperlink" property was set to "Yes." I changed that to "No," and set "Display As Hyperlink" to "Screen Only". No longer getting the url append when the field is edited. Why I failed to realize the OnClick event is always available is a total mystery. Thanks for setting me straight!